# Gatsby / Graphql - Can't display img from query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import Img from 'gatsby-image'


const ImageGallery = () => {


const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
query {
  images: allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images" }}) {
    edges {
      node {
        relativePath
        childImageSharp {
          id
          fluid {
            originalImg
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`)

 // Filters all the images from "gallery-one"

 const galleryImages = data.images.edges.filter(edge => 
  edge.node.relativePath.startsWith("gallery-one")
 )

console.log(data)
console.log(galleryImages)


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Gallery One</h1>
            {
             // Mapping over galleryImages array to display each image

              galleryImages.map((image) =>
                <div>
                // Returns relative path for each image
                {image.node.childImageSharp.fluid.originalImg}
                 // Returns nothing
                <Img fluid={image.node.childImageSharp.fluid.originalImg} />
                </div>
              )
            }
        </div>
    )
}


export default ImageGallery
```

With the first part in the map, it returns:

> /static/3608211e3ce3f78486c9e344b92332d9/5f7bf/20171107_155145.jpg
>
> /static/fccd9cdb1c9b525bfaf9282343d680a6/5f7bf/20171101_103124.jpg
>
> /static/cdcbaebc030e210debc70bdff7a8d539/5f7bf/20171107_155126.jpg
>
> /static/ef8708d7f536bd152c9ce98833d6d871/5f7bf/20171101_103218.jpg
>
> /static/1c3b4e40cb5044e604009935b625fa38/5f7bf/20171101_103138.jpg

One for each image in the 'gallery-one' folder, but I cannot figure out how to get it to display using Gatsby Img.

I feel like this is really close, but I can't seem to figure it out

```
fluid={image.node.childImageSharp.fluid.originalImg}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're almost there.

When you query an image to be displayed using `gatsby-image` you have 2 options:

- Use a GraphQL fragment:

  Instead of using `originalImg` you should use `...GatsbyImageSharpFluid` which will provide to the `fluid` object all information required.
- Querying all the data required. In this case you should use:

  ```
    fluid (maxWidth: 800) {
      aspectRatio
      src
      srcSet
      sizes
      originalImg
      originalName
    }
  ```

  *Disclaimer: the default `maxWidth` is `800px`. If you don't set it, it will take the default value.*

Once you gathered all the information, it needs to be passed to `<Img>` removing your `originalImg`, such as:

```
fluid={image.node.childImageSharp.fluid}
```

For further information check [Gatsby Image API documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-image/).